# Data read using spidev C does not agree with scope measurements

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, spi

I've been fighting with this for a while now and couldn't get anywhere. I am using the spidev and C to communicate with a camera and receive a jpeg picture.

To receive the picture: simply send `0x3C` and the camera will send the jpeg picture starting with `0xFF`, `0xD8` and ending with `0xFF`, `0xD9`.

Here is my code which I adapted from spidev_fdx.c for full duplex and running on RPi:

```
    int ret;
   
    struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer[2];
    unsigned char       buf[300000], *bp;
    int         status;

    memset(xfer, 0, sizeof xfer);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);

    buf[0] = BURST_FIFO_READ;//This is 0x3C = 0011 1100
    xfer[0].tx_buf = (unsigned long)buf;
    xfer[0].len = 1;
    xfer[0].cs_change = 0;//Keep CS low after sending 0x3C

    xfer[1].rx_buf = (unsigned long) buf;
    xfer[1].len = 300000;

printf("Starting fourth transfer...\n");
    delay_ms(2000);
    status = ioctl(spi_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(2), xfer);
    if (status < 0) 
        perror("SPI_IOC_MESSAGE");
   
    
    printf("Image received...\n");  
                
    for(int bufcnt = 0;bufcnt<100;bufcnt++){
        printf("%02x",buf[bufcnt]);
    }
```

Now here is the output of the last for loop which are the first 100 bytes:

```
00010101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

You can see that no where in here there is `0xFF`,`0xD8`. However, here is a picture from the scope:

[image]

The signals are from top to bottom: CS, Clock, MOSI, MISO.

The SPI mode is 0 so the clock idles at low and data is sampled at the rising edge.

You can see the 0x3C = 0011 1100 coming out on the blue line, and the camera responds with 0xFF, 0xD8 on the purple line. for reference, 0xFF = 1111 1111, 0xD8 = 1101 1000

That does not agree with the first 100 elements of buf printed above.I tried to read the last 100 elements and it was still garbage. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Note: I am aware that the default buffer size for spi is `4096`. I have already changed this to `300000` and c`at /sys/module/spidev/parameters/bufsiz` returns `300000`

Comment: No direct help, but have an upvote anyway for the debug and scope pic:)

Comment: most SPI chips must be 'selected during the whole data transfer sequence. But the scope display indicates the chip is only being selected for 1 clock cycle

Comment: regarding `if (status < 0) 
        perror("SPI_IOC_MESSAGE");
   
    
    printf("Image received...\n");`  when an I/O error occurs, do NOT continue as if everything was fine

Comment: most SPI chips need to be reference by their 'channel address' and weither the next operation is to be a read or write.  I don't see that being done in the posted info

Comment: @user3629249, CS is kept low for entire transfer, I don’t see what you’re talking about. IIRC `perror()` aborts the execution.

Comment: 300k buffer on stack?! Have you tried with a smaller buffer like 256 bytes? Also, are you sure you want to receive 300k? You have on buffer for read and write. Are you sure it’s okay?

Comment: I actually tried with a smaller buffer size and it worked and I got meaningful data. When I set the buffer size to higher than 65k, I start getting garbage. The image is about 200k so yes I need 300k buffer. You mentioned the stack, shall I allocate the buffer with malloc?

Comment: Ha, then you missed the crucial detail. 64K seems a DMA boundary and I believe that is a limitation of the SPI/DMA IPs on your board. So, you have to read in chunks. And yes, you have to use allocated memory in order to get DMA work **reliably**.

Comment: When commenting, don't forget to add `@nickname` in order to notify user you are replying to. I was suddenly noticed a comment here.